# What is the opposite of standoffish?

Tags: single-word-requests

What behavior (or appearance of behavior) would be considered the opposite of standoffish? While not necessary, a single word answer would be very interesting if it is exactly its opposite.

Comment: I imagine that either "welcoming" or "receptive" might work depending on the context.  "Friendly" also, but that feels less warm and therefore less opposite in meaning to me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be schooloffish? Trees come in stands, fish in schools.

Comment: Some other possibilities: warm, open.

Comment: @tchrist *Standoffish* is fine. You might find it right next to the butchersblock or the tableofflowers. *Context, context, context.* :P

Comment: Hi @Silicabello, jokes aside, would you mind elaborating on what sense you’re after? Antonyms are notorious for taking off in various directions.

Answer (score 1):

[Gregarious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gregarious) or [sociable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sociable) are two good options which both indicate someone who seeks out the company of others.

Answer (score 0):

**Chummy**, or **familiar**, both having a somewhat negative connotation, as does **standoffish**.

It depends on what you are trying to say, however.

In the Wiktionary, [chummy](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/chummy) is defined as “on, or trying to be on, intimate terms”. Sometimes chummy behavior is welcome, or at least describes a welcome state of affairs, e.g. among like-minded relatives at a family reunion.

At other times, though, it can be highly annoying, such as when a telemarketer starts off calling you by your first name, attempting to seem like a friend instead of a huckster.

Comment: I like "approachable" as an antonym to standoffish. "Accessible" might also work.